# R package "forecast": Daily data with weekly frequencies lead to wrong annual figures

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I am trying to fit both ETS and ARIMA models to daily sales data from 2017-01-01 to 2019-03-31

Using the R package "forecast" I have created a ts object from my data. Here, I used for frequency *7*. Unfortunatly, this has changed my date notation, as it can be seen below, such that every 7th period a new "year" starts, instead ofkeeping the old date format.

Question: How can I apply weekly seasonality from my data and at the same time keep the desired date structure with the Format "Year-month-day" (2017-01-01).

```
DF <- read_excel("....",
                 col_names = TRUE,
                 col_types = c("date", "numeric", "numeric", 
                               "numeric", "numeric","numeric","numeric"))
TS <- ts(DF[,2:6], , start = c(2017, 1), frequency = 7)
TS_ggseasonplot <- lapply(TS,function(x){ggseasonplot(x, polar=TRUE)})
```

Old Output before applying ts.

```
Date       V_1
   <date>       <dbl>
 1 2017-01-01       0
 2 2017-01-02     529
 3 2017-01-03     556
 4 2017-01-04     544
 5 2017-01-05     510
 6 2017-01-06     319
 7 2017-01-07       0
 8 2017-01-08       0
 9 2017-01-09    1296
10 2017-01-10     388
```

Afterwards:

```
Date         V_1    
2017.000       0      
2017.286     556   
2017.429     544    
2017.571     510    
2017.714     319      
2017.857       0      
2018.000       0      
2018.143    1296
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a big shortcoming of using ts objects to do forecasting, and a big motivator for why we're developing new packages to work directly with time series data frames (tsibble objects).

For the forecast package, you can use the lubridate package's `lubridate::date_decimal()` function to convert a decimal date back into a date.

```r
lubridate::date_decimal(2017.3287671233)
#> [1] "2017-05-01 00:00:00 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>